# Tinymce color button issue

Tags: javascript, dom, tinymce

I created a fiddle of what my issue is about: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/k5faab/31

To choose the color you need to click on the caret part of the button, not the button itself. When you click on the button itself nothing happens.

In the plugin (I am using tinymce 4.5) the button shows as such:

```
e.addButton("forecolor", {
type: "colorbutton",
tooltip: "Text Color",
format: "forecolor",
 panel: {
        origin: "forecolor",
        role: "application",
        ariaRemember: !0,
        html: r,
        onclick: a
    }
```

I tried changing `type: "colorbutton"` to `type: "button"` and `type: "menubutton"` and `type: "panelbutton"`  but it didn't do the trick. Although they all show as clickable buttons the color picker pretty much stops functioning.

I tried to figure out what their `type: "colorbutton"` actually is, but couldn't find anything that relates to it in `tinymce.min.js` or in the plugin itself.

How do I make the entire button clickable?

PS I also upload the entire plugin script here in case someone wants to take a look at the script itself: https://jsfiddle.net/kj0tmwer/

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The issue was in tinymce.min.js.
Maybe it will help someone out there. Find: `<button role="presentation" hidefocus="1" type="button" tabindex="-1">` add `class="mce-open"` to it.